# Ruby analog of "this" (access class instance from inside)

Tags: ruby, oop

In many languages there is a concept of `this` available from inside an object (e.g. class instance). Consider this generic pseudocode:

```
class Foo {
    int x;

    constructor() {
        this.x = 10;
    }
}
```

Here `this` provides access to the object from inside. It can be useful in numerous ways.

Now, I can't find how we can access `this` from inside Ruby class. I see that properties are accessible by `@` prefix and methods are accessible by their names, but these are just parts of an instance, not an instance itself. So the question is: how we access a full Ruby object from inside of that object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `self`:

https://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-self-cheat-sheet

https://airbrake.io/blog/ruby/self-ruby-overview

Comment: Yes it is. I thought that `self` is for `static` stuff, but wasn't aware that it means different things for different callsites

Comment: `self` is not used for "`static` stuff". In fact, there is *no such thing* as `static` in Ruby. All method calls are always dynamic, all methods are always virtual. Also, `self` always means exactly one thing and one thing only: it is a reference to the current object. It does *not* have different meanings for different callsites.

Comment: `self` is not a method. (`Object#self` was one of many proposed names for the method that is now known as `Object#itself`.) `self` is a keyword that denotes some sort of "special variable" if you will. I don't think there is an official name for it.

Comment: By "static" I meant "related to a class in general an not to one particular class instance"

Answer (score 3):

In ruby, you should use `self` instead of `this`, is the equivalent.

Now, we have a difference between a instance and a class method.

See the example:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.class_method_example
     return self
   end

   def instance_method_example
     return self
   end
end
```

In the first case, we can compare the class with the result:

```
Person.class_method_example == Person  # this returns true
```

In the second, we can only call the method with a Person instance:

```
Person.first.instance_method_example  == Person.first # this returns true
```

UPDATE
In second example, i'am presuming the extend of `ActiveRecord::Base` to use the `first` method

Comment: The second example is not exactly viable since `Person::first` is not a method. Also your method definitions are missing the `def` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot about the `def`. Presuming if the class, extends the `ActiveRecord::Base`, the first is a class method, returns the first (or N firsts) records of this class.